# Insight.database executing sql function

Tags: sql

To execute sql function or procedure Insight database in the guts executes a query to get info about stored procedures or function and its parameters.
But in the case of sql function query returns the first parameter name empty.

for example:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT ParameterName = p.Name, SchemaName = s.name, TypeName = t.Name
FROM sys.parameters p
LEFT JOIN sys.types t ON (p.user_type_id = t.user_type_id)
LEFT JOIN sys.schemas s ON (t.schema_id = s.schema_id)
WHERE p.object_id = OBJECT_ID(@Name)',N'@Name nvarchar(4000)', @Name=N'dbo.FuncName'
```

This query returns parameters list, but first parameter is empty.
In this case Insight.Database fails to execute query.

Is there a way to resolve it without using adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no way for a SqlCommand to execute a SQL function directly (regardless of whether the parameters are correct).

To call a function directly, you would need to use a SQL statement. Example:

```
select * from dbo.fn_GetUserId_Username(@Username)
```

In this case, Insight should pick up the parameters correctly.

Comment: I agree. With this in mind I had to find another solution with your approach